# mail() method using PHP, how do I set the sender?

Tags: php, email

I'm using iPage for my website, and I'm using a simple mail() method to send test mails from my page.  On iPage, I have email capabilities via mark@domain.com.  But when I send an email out, it comes from the iPage server and is sent from ipg.domain@boscustweb3506.eigbox.net, which is quite ugly looking!

Is there a way I can use the mail() method in php to send an email from my page that will use the shorter sender above?  Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: `mail("you@somwhere.com","HW","Hello World","From: mark@domain.com"`?

Comment: There is a possibility that whatever hosting service you are using is not capable of sending a message with a custom "from" set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to add a header named From. this code will send with the mail address webmaster@example.com:

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, You can add the From header to customise the sender address.

```
$from ='mark@domain.com';
$headers = 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
...
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```